# Conditional expectations one more time

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, conditional-expectation

Please someone verifies my results:

**1)** $E \Big( \int_0^3W_t^2dt|F_1\Big)=$(editing in progress)

---

**2)** $E \Big( \int_0^2 (tW_t+t^2)dt|F_1\Big)=E \Big( \int_0^2 tW_tdt|F_1\Big)+E \Big( \int_0^2 t^2dt\Big)=E \Big( \int_0^1 tW_tdt|F_1\Big)+E \Big( \int_1^2 tW_tdt|F_1\Big)+\frac{8}{3}=\int_0^1 tW_tdt+\frac{8}{3} $

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, the equality $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_1^3 W_t^2 \, dt \mid \mathcal{F}_1 \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_1^3 W_t^2 \, dt \right)$$ does not hold (mind that $W_t^2$, $t \geq 1$, is *not* independent of $\mathcal{F}_1$). Write instead $$\begin{align*} \int_1^3 W_t^2 \, dt &= \int_1^3 ((W_t-W_1)+W_1)^2 \, dt \\ &= \int_1^3 (W_t-W_1)^2 \, dt + 2 W_1 \int_1^3 (W_t-W_1) \, dt+ 2 W_1^2. \end{align*}$$

> **Solution:** $$\int_0^1 W_t^2 \, dt +2 + 2 W_1^2.$$

2. No, this is not correct. Note that $\mathbb{E}(W_t \mid \mathcal{F}_1) \neq W_1$ for all $t \leq 1$.

> **Solution:** $$\int_0^1 t W_t \, dt + \frac{3}{2} W_1 + \frac{8}{3}.$$

Comment: oh right... I get it now

Comment: Is the second one ok now?

Comment: @luka5z No, mind that $$\mathbb{E}(W_t \mid \mathcal{F}_1) \neq 0$$ for $t \geq 1$. (I have added the solutions to my answer; hopefully, there are no typos in there.)

Comment: But isnt $\int_1^2 tW_tdt$ independent of $F_1$?

Comment: @luka5z Why should it? $W_t-W_1$ is independent from $F_1$, but $W_t$ is not. [Here $t \geq 1$]

Comment: oh right, I must focus more on it